# Lock X axis in Graph Editor, to edit keyframe timing, exclude changes to keyframe values

Tags: graph-editor

I want to use the graph editor in Blender 2.83 (Windows 10) to move several keyframes backwards in time (X axis), without accidentally changing the values (Y axis). How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Highlite/select the keyframes required and press 'G X'.  Drag as required.

Comment: @Edgel3D Thanks! I didn't even think to use the same keyboard shortcuts as in the 3D viewport. I should have thought of that! Feel free to write an answer, and I will mark it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @trevor Sullivan .  It;s a bit too sparse for an answer and I see the comment has been upvoted anyway  After several years with Blender, if it wasn't for this site and contributors, Youtube etc, I think I'd still be floundering with the basics!